# Output process of a G/M/1 queue

Tags: probability-theory, queueing-theory

> What is the output distribution of a GI/M/1 (general input process and exponential service times) queue.

The GI/M/1 is according to [Kendall's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_notation): arrivals are independent but we do not know the distribution of intervals, service time follows an exponential distribution, and there is only one server.

For the M/M/1 queue (exponential inter-arrival times input process), it is easy since the output process is exponential inter-departures. But, for a general input process, I don't know how to calculate the output process, i.e. the distribution of the time intervals between outputs.

Comment: @Raphael, it is standard notation in queueing theory. And this model (general inter-arrival distribution, exponential service times, 1 server) has been studied a lot, but as far as I know little can be said in general.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This seems to be a rather pure mathematics question, even though applications in CS are apparent. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here over the course of, say, about a week, please flag for migration to [math.SE] if that's what you want.

Comment: @PålGD Really? At my department, not even probability theory is mandatory, let alone this special case. Are you positive that it is standard in the sense of "most curricula around the world contain it", not only in a more localized sense?